# Dipole oscillators question from Feynman lectures 1.28-29

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, dipole, antennas

I am confused by the Feynman lectures Vol1Ch28-29. In all the pictures, there is an electric dipole oscillating vertically. We're assuming the intensity is $E^2$ and that in the far r limit $E$ depends only on the perpendicular component of the acceleration. So the logic in the first picture is that since the E field only depends on the perpendicular acceleration, the top and bottom are 0, and the left and right are the strongest intensity.

But in the 2nd and 3rd pictures (with 2 vertically vibrating dipoles 1/2 with charges separated by 1/2 a wavelength of emitted $E$), this logic isn't present clearly, as the diagram labeled (b), which is $180^o$ out of phase, has full amplitude at top and bottom. I get that it's out of phase, but by the logic of the first photo, shouldn't the top and bottom areas always have 0 intensity, since they're in the 'plane of sight' of both dipoles?

Can someone explain why this isn't true?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: One diagram is a side view, the other is a top view.

Longer answer: In the figures showing the intensity due to two dipoles [a) and b)], the direction of dipole moment oscillation (and thus acceleration of the charged particles involved) is not in the plane of the paper(screen), but perpendicular to it. So the far fields from both fields add up constructively at points of b) denoted by "4". These fields are almost zero at any point above the two dipoles (above the figure). By the same logic, the field at point 3 in the first figure is zero.